# Replace divided by symbol in numeric column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame with following contents:

```
df$old_price <- c('SR 2356' , 'SR 785' , 'SR 50/4 pack', 'SR 10/4 pack,'SR 490')
```

How do I replace values in `old_price` column where values such 'SR 50/4 pack' or 'SR 10/4 pack to give out 12.5 and 2.5 respectively without corrupting the data?

I tried `df$old_price <- as.integer(gsub('[a-zA-Z]', '', df$old_price))`. However, it seems like it creates strange column values.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This could be another solution:

```
library(stringr)

unlist(lapply(str_extract(vec, "\\d.*\\d"), \(x) eval(parse(text = x))))

[1] 2356.0  785.0   12.5    2.5  490.0
```

An alternative regex solution to suggested by dear [Ian Campbell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13095326/ian-campbell):

```
unlist(lapply(str_extract(vec, "[\\d,./]+"), \(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
```

Comment: Might try something like `"[\\d,./]+"`, that way you don't get any errant letters. Otherwise, I really like this approach.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Ian, I also added this to the solution. I kinda imagined there might be characters such as `+` or `-` involved but I guess that's just `/`. Anyway so glad to see you hear again.

Comment: I am getting this error                                                                                            
 ```Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src): <text>:1:58: unexpected input
1: df %>% unlist(lapply(str_extract(old_price, "[\\d,./]+"),\
                                                             ^
Traceback:```

Comment: Does the second solution returns such error or also the first one?

Comment: unfortunately, Yes. \ before (x) seems to be the issue.

Comment: Oh use `function(x)` instead of that. This is a new feature in the latest version of R. Some older version cannot recognize it.

Comment: @Vikram has it solved your error?

Comment: it is working perfectly for small example I gave in the question but it does not work on my dataset . Giving this error. ```Error in parse(text = x): <text>:1:2: unexpected ','
1: 2,
     ^
Traceback:

1. unlist(lapply(str_extract(df$old_price, "[\\d,./]+"), function(x) eval(parse(text = x))))
2. lapply(str_extract(df$old_price, "[\\d,./]+"), function(x) eval(parse(text = x)))
3. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
4. eval(parse(text = x))   # at line 1 of file <text>
5. parse(text = x)   # at line 1 of file <text>```

Comment: I understand. I think in that case you should share a data sample which represents your data set better, sometimes a data sample could be too simplistic or maybe other patterns exist that this regex cannot match.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR Hi my dear friend. Hope you're doing fine. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how stable this is, but you could try

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(new.price = as.integer(str_extract(old.price, "\\d+(?=/|$)")) / coalesce(as.integer(str_extract(old.price, "(?<=/)\\d+")), 1))
```

This returns

```r
     old.price new.price
1      SR 2356    2356.0
2       SR 785     785.0
3 SR 50/4 pack      12.5
4 SR 10/4 pack       2.5
5       SR 490     490.0
```

Comment: Martiiiin, how are you doing? long time no chat.

Comment: Do not know why but for some values for eg- 'SR 2375' the value is coming out as 375. Similar with  other 4 digit numbers having SR. It is ending up with 3 digit instead of 4.

Comment: @Vikram Can't reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: @MartinGal - yes seems like my engine has issues since it is working perfectly with the small example though..

Answer (score 2):

To get numeric values of character with division symbol `/`, an alternative way is to split the character so that the numbers without `/` are extracted. After that, the extracted numbers are converted to numeric, and then division of the numbers is conducted by using `/`.

```
# Define the function
getNumber <- function(string_vect){
   extracted_number <- gsub(".*?([0-9/0-9]+).*","\\1", string_vect)
   split_number <- strsplit(extracted_number, "/") |> unlist() |> as.numeric()
   divided_number <- split_number[1]/split_number[2]
   return(divided_number)
}
#Apply the function to the column
mydf <- data.frame(price = c("SR 50/4 pack", "SR 10/4"))

lapply(mydf$price, getNumber) |> unlist()
#[1] 12.5  2.5
```

If the column contains mixed characters, some of them with `/`, and others without it, the function can be modified with conditionals `if` and `else` as follows:

```
 getAllnumber <- function(string_vect){
     extracted_number <- gsub(".*?([0-9/0-9]+).*","\\1", string_vect)
     if(grepl("/", string_vect)){
     split_number <- strsplit(extracted_number, "/") |> unlist() |> as.numeric()
     resulted_number <- split_number[1]/split_number[2]
     }
     else{
         resulted_number <- extracted_number |> as.numeric()
     }
     return(resulted_number)
 }

#apply the function to the column

mydf <- data.frame(price = c("SR 2356","SR 785","SR 50/4 pack",
                            "SR 10/4 pack","SR 490"))

lapply(mydf$price, getAllnumber) |> unlist()
#[1] 2356.0  785.0   12.5    2.5  490.0

# or 
vapply(mydf$price, getAllnumber, numeric(1))
#     SR 2356      SR 785 SR 50/4 pack   SR 10/4 pack    SR 490 
#     2356.0        785.0         12.5            2.5     490.0
```

**Edit to show the same function with no pipe**

An exactly same function as can be defined without using any `|>` pipe as follows.

```
getAllnumber2 <- function(string_vect){
     extracted_number <- gsub(".*?([0-9/0-9]+).*","\\1", string_vect)
     if(grepl("/", string_vect)){
     split_number <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(extracted_number, "/")))
     resulted_number <- split_number[1]/split_number[2]
     }
     else{
         resulted_number <- as.numeric(extracted_number)
     }
     return(resulted_number)
 }

mydf <- data.frame(price = c("SR 2356","SR 785","SR 50/4 pack",
                            "SR 10/4 pack","SR 490"))

unlist(lapply(mydf$price, getAllnumber2))
```

This code will return the same result as the function with pipe:

```
#[1] 2356.0  785.0   12.5    2.5  490.0
```

Comment: getting this error : ```Error in unlist(as.numeric(strsplit(extracted_number, "/"))): 'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
Traceback:

1. unlist(lapply(df$old_price, getAllnumber))
2. lapply(df$old_price, getAllnumber)
3. FUN(X[[i]], ...)
4. unlist(as.numeric(strsplit(extracted_number, "/")))   # at line 4 of file <text> ```

Comment: I have just checked again the `getAllnumber` function and apply it to `mydf$price` in the example above. It worked correctly with no error. Based on the error message you got, I suspect that the cause of the error is probably the wrong order of `unlist() |> as.numeric()`.  In my code above : `unlist()` is put first, and then `as.numeric()`.  It means, the code changes the resulted list to a character vector, and then changes the vector to a numeric vector. When I tried to reverse the order : `as.numeric() |> unlist()`, I got the exactly same error message as yours.

Comment: i used the same order yet getting that error. I am starting to feel maybe Kaggle is the issue ?

Comment: OK maybe there is some issue with the engine, not the code. I have edited my answer to show the same function defined without using any `|>` pipe.  To test the `getAllnumber2` function, please run the code at https://rdrr.io/snippets/  or any other website with online R editor.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using regex matching with `str_match` from `stringr`.

```
#sample data
input <- structure(list(item_id = 1:5, 
                    price = c(265L, 995L, 20L, 7L, 421L), 
                    old_price = c("105", "No old price", "SR 50/4 pack", "SR 10/4 pack", "520")), 
                    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

# item_id price    old_price
# 1       265      105
# 2       995      No old price
# 3       20       SR 50/4 pack
# 4       7        SR 10/4 pack
# 5       421      520
```

The regex expression groups each value when a match is made (e.g. `50`/`4`). I then use a loop to identify records that matched and update the record with the new value.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(input)) {
  x <- as.numeric(str_match(input[i,]$old_price, "(\\d+)\\/(\\d+)")[,2]) 
  y <- as.numeric(str_match(input[i,]$old_price, "(\\d+)\\/(\\d+)")[,3])
  
    if(!is.na(x) && !is.na(y)) {
      input[i,]$old_price <- x / y
    }
  
}

# item_id price    old_price
# 1       265      105
# 2       995      No old price
# 3       20       12.5
# 4       7        2.5
# 5       421      520
```